# Clang does not accept -shared -fPIC -pie compiler flags simultaneously

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Given by below code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void output()
{
  printf("hello \n");
}

int main()
{
  output();
  return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled by below command:

```
gcc hello.c -shared -fPIC -pie -o libhello.so -Wl,-E
```

The generated **libhello.so** is not only a shared lib, but also an executable. However, when change **gcc** to **clang** as below

```
clang-10 hello.c -shared -fPIC -pie -o libhello.so -Wl,-E
```

The compilation gives below warning:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

When executing **libhello.so** compiled by **clang-10**, it also crashed.

Question:
1.   Is it possible to use clang compile runnable shared lib as gcc?

Note : This question is asked only for my own curiosity and I am not facing any practical problem.

Comment: Looks like `clang` does not like generating executable shared libraries unlike GCC, it therefore doesn't add standard libc functions to start the program and it also doesn't add the required `PT_INTERP` ELF program header, causing a segfault when starting because the kernel thinks the program must start without an interpreter. You could try writing your own `_start()` function and see what happens.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, thanks a lot of your help. Beside ```_start()```, we also have to force clang-10 to generate INTERP segment in the shared object program header. A detail of the example is given in the question as well.

Comment: @MikeKinghan. Thanks for your tips, I post a new answer as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As warning by the clang-10, clang-10 does not generate below things as GCC compilers:

1. INTERP segment in shared lib's program header
2. _start() function

Both of them can be manually as below

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

void output()
{
  printf("hello \n");
}

int main()
{
  output();
  return 0;
}

void _start()
{
  printf("hello.c : %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
  exit(0);
}
```

However, it's better to use `-Wl,-e,YourEntryFunction` flags to create shared object runnable instead of the approach presented in the above question.